# Chef recipe fails at compiling cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I want to encrypt all my chef data_bags and set the decryption key on clients VMs in /etc/chef/secret_key so at chef-client run it will decrypt the data bag with this key. For this I have the following resources in recipe:

```
# Put the secret key in /etc/chef
cookbook_file '/etc/chef/rd_seceret_key' do
  source 'rd_seceret_key'
  action :create
end
# Get the credentials from the databag for the current environment
credentials = data_bag_item('pinpoint', node.chef_environment.downcase, IO.read('/etc/chef/rd_seceret_key'))
....
```

Now at compiling it tries to solve IO.read('/etc/chef/rd_seceret_key') which of course it doesn't exists yet until the chef client will set it from file like is set in the recipe above.

```
Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/rd_seceret_key
98>> credentials = data_bag_item('pinpoint', node.chef_environment.downcase, IO.read('/etc/chef/rd_seceret_key'))
```

Now my question is how can I prioritize this to set first the cookbook_file. Of course I want to do this from one chef-client not separating recipe.

Comment: Can you use lazy evaluation for this, or else somehow split the cookbooks in two?

Comment: I don't know what lazy evaluation is and yes it's fine to split the cookbook but I want to hit chef-client once.

Comment: Does this help https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-evaluation

Comment: Now I see what lazy evaluation is but I don't think it will help since we have to solve IO.read('/etc/chef/rd_seceret_key')) at compilling.

Comment: Give me 5 mins to try :)

Comment: I'm using chef server 12 and I'm facing NoMethodError
No resource or method named `lazy' for `Chef::Recipe "web"' while defining the secret_key attribute with lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ to see how to force things to run at compile time.

That said, please don't do this. Distributing the data bag key through Chef itself defeats the entire point of the security model and is literally pointless.

Comment: Nice article! only_if bypass this from compilation phase. Thanks, indeed is not a good ideea I'm trying just a POC. It would be super usefull if you have some articles or ideea how to use corectly an encryption data bag.